# PHP url path is html?var=something&&var_2=somathing_else possible?

Tags: php, url, joomla

I have a Joomla website. The suffix of the url path assign by the SEF of Joomla assigns .html to the end of my pages URLs.

If I want to get information from the URL, is it possible to use:

domain.com/name_assign_by_Joomla_SEF.html?var=something&&var_2=something_else

for the $_GET to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may work, if the .html was added by .htaccess
if not, an this is a cached page, u may have some problems using $_GET

Comment: Thank you, $_GET works even if the end of the url path is .html?var... vs. .php?var...

Comment: yes, get is a sending method, it works even if there no extention.